# Can an electrical pole be replaced in an Eruv without notifying the community?

Tags: eruv-chatzerot

For a simple reduction,

Let's say there is an Eruv with an electrical pole-fishing line barrier and one of the electrical poles need to be serviced. Can one of those electrical poles be replaced by a non-Jew with the fishing line attached in a similar fashion?

Does it matter if the electrical pole doesn't move at all? Does it matter if the electrical pole moves 10 feet? Is utility maintenance of this sort simple?

I see this in the FAQ, but no further explaination,

> Sometimes things break all by themselves, sometimes cars or trucks knock down poles, and occasionally the owner of the pole will replace it with one a few feet away and the new one doesn’t work for us.

Comment: A non Jew can put up the pile adnd string, but some would have an issue if they are too far apart (approx. 40 ft)

Comment: There is no general answer here. Some differences matter and some don't. That's why you have inspectors and experts to evaluate every new situation.

Comment: The pole-and-string is not a religious ritual per se. If the Jewish eruv checkers see that a pole's been relocated by someone but it still meets the technical requirements, great. But it's complicated enough that you should have Jewish experts aware of what's happening.

Comment: @Shalom , Chatzkel, Double AA, it seems you have answers. Might I suggest you post them as such?

Comment: Please take msh210's advice. On this site I get most of my answers in comments. That's unique on this site.

Comment: You also get more God Points when I upvote an answer then a comment.